# How can I make the user agree to my EULA before installing my google-chrome-extension from the Google Chrome Webstore?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have developed a Google Chrome Extension and am going to put it up on the chrome webstore. I also have an EULA for the end-user to accept before installing the extension or whenever the EULA may change. I have searched and searched but not found any way to tell Chrome to display the EULA before install and not continue with the install unless the user accepts the agreement. Based on my research it seems that I'll have to implement that logic on my own. However, I thought that I might ask here in case I'd missed something. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your extension code won't run until it's installed, and the Chrome Web Store doesn't provide any hooks for developers to add conditional logic, whether server-side or client-side, to the installation process. Your best bet is to listen to the [onInstalled](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#event-onInstalled) event, put up appropriate UI, and disable important functionality until the user agrees to your terms.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer my question. Let me wait a little bit more to see if anybody else out there has any thing else to input.

Answer (score 2):

@sowbug appears to be correct. The EULA functionality which Chrome Web Store provides is implicit in the use of the Web Store by your customers. This is stated in the user's Terms of Service at https://ssl.gstatic.com/chrome/webstore/intl/en/gallery_tos.html:

> 1.3 You accept the Terms by either (1) clicking to agree or accept where these options are presented to you, or (2) actually using the
>   Web Store application or web service.

This EULA is found at the devloper website (https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/terms#) and has the key point:

> 5.2 You grant to the user a non-exclusive, worldwide, and perpetual
>   license to perform, display, and use the Products and any content
>   contained in, accessed by, or transmitted through the Products in
>   connection with Google Chrome. **If you choose, you may include a
>   separate end user license agreement (EULA) in your Product that will
>   govern the user’s rights to the Products in lieu of the previous
>   sentence.**

So you may provide your own EULA, but it has to be "in your Product" (i.e., created yourself).